# How to resize Brand Image?

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I'm very new to CSS and Bootstrap.

I have large brand image (logotipo-white), and I want to resize it to 30% of its original size. However, when I apply the following code the image appear small but still occupies the original space, pushing the nav links to another line.

How can I solve this?

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class = "navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class = "navbar-inner">
        <div class = "container">
            <ul class = "brand"><img src="images/logotipo-white.png"></ul>
            <ul class = "nav">
                <li class = "active">
                    <a href = "#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href = "#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href = "#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href = "#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body{
background-image:url('../images/bg-green.jpg') ;
}
.brand img{
max-width: 30%;
}
```

Comment: is this what you are getting? & What are you trying to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/Ba7V2/

Comment: I tried all those solutions but they didn't work. Maybe I have not explained myself well. Here is the website, with some content other than the navbar: www.institutoalpha.org.br

Comment: When you resize the browser the nav links go to another line :(. Notice that this page has not the same html. I'm trying to remake this page in order to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the html don't use an ul for your brand as this is not needed, use an a-tag instead:

```
<a class="brand" href="#"><img src="images/logotipo-white.png" /></a>
```

and to solve your issue, in css do the following: CSS:

```
.navbar .brand { 
    max-height: 40px;
    max-width: 30%; 
    overflow: visible;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's built with bootstrap, then everything is placed within Spans. Trying making the span it is in smaller.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `<img>` directly inside `<ul>`.

The markup could be like this :

```
        <ul class = "nav">
            <li class="brand"><img src="images/logotipo-white.png"></li>
            <li class = "active">
                <a href = "#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href = "#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Or this :

```
        <ul class = "brand"><li><img src="images/logotipo-white.png"></li></ul>
        <ul class = "nav">
            <li class = "active">
                <a href = "#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href = "#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
```

or this :

```
        <div class = "brand"><img src="images/logotipo-white.png"></div><!--make me float/display:inline-block/other -->
        <ul class = "nav">
            <li class = "active">
                <a href = "#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href = "#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Joomla! 3 template css add max-width: 80% to .brand line 7137

```
    .brand {
    color: #001a27;
    max-width: 80%;
    -webkit-transition: color .5s linear;
    -moz-transition: color .5s linear;
    -o-transition: color .5s linear;
    transition: color .5s linear;
    }
```